# How to get Laravel 5 working on Heroku?

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, laravel-5

I've gotten Laravel to work on Heroku before, however following the same and/or similar steps don't seem to work for me any more.

I have a brand new Laravel 5 installation after Windows 10 install (so you understand that this was actually completely new). I installed Homestead, checked that the Laravel app worked on Homestead, and pushed to Heroku. Updated information as follows:

Through CLI:

```
heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php
heroku config:set LARAVEL_ENV=heroku
heroku run composer update
```

added Procfile:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public
```

This ends with the server displaying:

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

How can I enable debugging on Heroku or figure out what went wrong? I looked at the changelog for Laravel and it seems that they've gone from 5.1 to 5.1.4 since I last did this, however I'm not familiar enough with things to know what changes may have caused this issue.

Comment: You need a local `.env` file to set up a local/debugging environment. Run `cp .env.example .env` to use the default one (and delete it once you have finished, since I think this is for local envs only). It will reveal the problem in a proper error message.

Comment: Thanks for noticing that I missed the step in my description of the problem. I actually did add a .env file.

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out. With the new Laravel update to 5.1.4 some extra security has been added. This means that a 16 char appkey no longer works. As many have found out editing app.php in Config helps.

config/app.php

```
 'key' => env('APP_KEY', 'SomeRandomStringSomeRandomString'),
```

'SomeRandomStringSomeRandomString' actually allows the app to run. This is a 32 char key, which is the new minimum. Hopefully this helps everyone. I know I ran into a lot of frustration when my previous methods no longer worked.

Also note, this means that you are on a environment without its own appkey. Probably will want to generate a new 32char key for security.

Answer (score 3):

Following on from your answer, this appears to be the correct way to set up your application key locally. Firstly, ensure your environment file exists in the root of the project:

```
cp .env.example .env
```

Then set encryption keys inside the app:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

For non-development installations, you will probably want to set this environment variable (and any others, such as database connection strings) in your Apache vhost instead:

```
SetEnv APP_KEY SomeRandomStringSomeRandomString
```

Comment: [Here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-laravel#setting-a-laravel-encryption-key) is the official document